# Should I use a single Model object for the whole SPA or many small models for each component?

Tags: javascript, architecture

I am thinking about how to organize Model in my webapp. I have two options, as I see it:

1. Create a single globally available Model object, then on instantiating new components they must register themselves in the Model object via methods, then update it when their state changes. Others would listen to changes from the Model by some key.
2. Create a model object for each component and let others know via some Event dispatcher about their state change.

In 1st case I feel like it will be easier to manage all the state change in one place, have more standardized way of doing it, while with the latter scenario I think it will be harder to maintain consistence over the system.

What are the factors I should base the decision on?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first but adding the idea of the second: Instead of the components checking constantly the keys for changes you can make the only model signal the components when needed after they register. You can pass the signal/callback with the register itself.

That way you don't need to create an army of models that update themselves (that might also mean you have to avoid cyclic propagation). In addition to this, if I understand correctly it would violate the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). Also it looks worse both memory and performance wise.